# Fetch data from odk using api

Tags: odk

I want to integrate odk data with an application(accepts json/xml). I need to know about how i can access the odk data directly using a api which returns json. have installed odk briefcase which can be used to fetch data from odk server but i need only api's.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to do this long back, but resorted to streaming data to my google drive directly from ODK and then using the google API to get data to my application.

Hope this helps.